# How to give stroke width evenly to rounded svg hexagon?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have made a rounded hexagon with stroke width but the top and bottom curves are darker. How to give the stroke width evenly to border? Here's my svg code

```
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 200.91789367798975 232" style="filter: drop-shadow(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.498039) 0px 0px 10px);">
                <path stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.8" fill="none" d="M79.67433714816835 11.999999999999998Q100.45894683899488 0 121.2435565298214 12L180.13328398716322 46Q200.91789367798975 58 200.91789367798975 82L200.91789367798975 150Q200.91789367798975 174 180.13328398716322 186L121.2435565298214 220Q100.45894683899488 232 79.67433714816835 220L20.784609690826528 186Q0 174 0 150L0 82Q0 58 20.784609690826528 46Z">
                </path>
            </svg>
```

Here's the fiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/4e6LkLjs/

Comment: The sides of your hexagon are falling off the sides of the viewport...

Comment: Changing the `viewbox="-1 0 203 232"` makes it fit.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much.. @ Niet the Dark Absol

Answer (score 2):

Just give it some width and height and it will work. Stroke width is even on your svg, you just don't see the whole shape as it gets out of svg bounds.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="700" height="700" viewbox="0 0 200.91789367798975 232" style="filter: drop-shadow(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.498039) 0px 0px 10px);">
                <path stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.8" fill="none" d="M79.67433714816835 11.999999999999998Q100.45894683899488 0 121.2435565298214 12L180.13328398716322 46Q200.91789367798975 58 200.91789367798975 82L200.91789367798975 150Q200.91789367798975 174 180.13328398716322 186L121.2435565298214 220Q100.45894683899488 232 79.67433714816835 220L20.784609690826528 186Q0 174 0 150L0 82Q0 58 20.784609690826528 46Z">
                </path>
            </svg>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4e6LkLjs/1/